# String Operation on captured group in re Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
str1 = "abc = def"
```

I want to convert it to:

```
str2 = "abc = #Abc#"
```

I am trying this:

```
re.sub("(\w+) = (\w+)",r"\1 = %s" % ("#"+str(r"\1").title()+"#"),str1)
```

but it returns: (without the string operation done)

```
"abc = #abc#"
```

- What is the possible reason `.title()` is not working.?
- How to use string operation on the captured group in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `lambda`.

**Ex:**

```
import re
str1 = "abc = def"
print( re.sub("(?P<one>(\w+)) = (\w+)",lambda match: r'{0} = #{1}#'.format(match.group('one'), match.group('one').title()), str1) )
```

**Output:**

```
abc = #Abc#
```

Comment: @NishantBhakta: See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 6):

You can see what's going on with the help of a little function:

```
import re

str1 = "abc = def"

def fun(m):
    print("In fun(): " + m)
    return m

str2 = re.sub(r"(\w+) = (\w+)",
    r"\1 = %s" % ("#" + fun(r"\1") + "#"),
    #                   ^^^^^^^^^^
    str1)
```

Which yields

```
In fun(): \1
```

So what you are basically trying to do is to change `\1` (**not** the substitute!) to an uppercase version which obviously remains `\1` literally. The `\1` is replaced only **later** with the captured content than your call to `str.title()`.

Go with a lambda function as proposed by @Rakesh.